# Statistic problem ( some problem with understanding)

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I got this problem in my home exercise at the University. I think I solved it, but I am not sure, that my solution is right. **Can somebody check it?**

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two events on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$, with $\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{1}{4}.$
> Determine the value of $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B^c)$ if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

**My answer :**

$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B^c)$=$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{1}{3}$, because since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint we have $A \cap B=\emptyset$ and if $x \in A$ then $x \in B^c$.
So that will mean $A \cap B^c=A$ and now we can apply probability on the both sides.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: @user469053 thank you!

Comment: Final result $ \frac13$ is correct, but explanation is not totally correct. If $P(B)= \frac34$, you will explain exactly the same way, you will say $P(A \cap B^c)= \frac13$, and it will be wrong.

Comment: @Lourrran where is the problem? How can I explain this right? Can u write, please?

Comment: To be fair, @Lourrran $\Pr(A)=\frac{1}{3},\Pr(B)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ are contradictory.  The OP correctly takes into account all of the stated hypotheses and uses the fact that $A,B$ are disjoint and explains their reasoning for when and how they use that fact.

Comment: @ mathguruu, I would not worry about it.  If anything, I would rearrange the last section to have the conclusion to be after the logic that leads to the conclusion, but that is just a matter of presentation and not a matter of the logic being incorrect.  I would also be more consistent in presentation, you wrote a $\mathbb{B}$ there rather than $B$ for instance.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh, ok , thank you so much!

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:elementary-set-theory]?

Comment: Argh !  I did not see that $Pr(B)=\frac34$ was not possible with other hypothesis !

Comment: I have covered your "concern" in my answer , @Lourrran , in the penultimate line [[ in square brackets ]] indicating that negative values occur in your case where $A$ & $B$ total to more than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has got the answer & is looking for verification.
OP has also tagged it set theory , hence I will give a verification based on that using Venn Diagrams.

Let us make a Standard Venn Diagram & see that "Disjoint" indicates that the Inter-Section is $0$ Probability.
Hence , let us make the Second Venn Diagram where the is no Inter-Section.
Observe that $B^C$ totally covers $A$ , hence $A \cap B^C = A$

[image: VENN DIAGRAM]

Hence , we make the last Diagram where we insert the Probability values.
[[ In Case , the outer area had negative value ( $A$ & $B$ total up to more than $1$ ) , then it will be inconsistent. Luckily , that is not the Case here. ]]

Hence $P(A \cap B^C)=P(A)=1/3$